# Create unsyncable (online only) Google Drive folder

Tags: google-drive, synchronization

I created a folder in Google Drive, which synced to all my devices. Then I decided to make it Online Only. Instead of **going into *each* device → preferences → unchecking this folder from the sync list**, is there such a setting on the web version, so that it unsyncs from all my devices?

(And prevents devices that haven't been used yet from syncing it in the future, if their preferences are set to "Sync Everything in My Drive")

Comment: Doesn't appear to be possible. I'll keep looking but it really looks like you'll need to visit each device and tell it what folders to sync.

Answer (score 5):

## Short answer

At this time there isn't a option on Google Drive to make a folder unsyncable.

## Explanation

Google Drive sync settings to exclude folders from syncing are only available in the Google Drive for PC/Mac. They are not available on

- the web app
- the offline settings
- the mobile apps for Android and iOS.

These settings only allow to choose if all the folders will be synced or only few of the them at the root level. If any of the root level folders is selected, all the folders inside it will be synced. These settings only apply for the device where Google Drive for PC/Mac is installed.

## References

- [Choose what to sync to your computer - Google Drive Help](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375083?hl=en)
- [Create and manage folders in Drive on Android - Google Drive Help](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3421276?hl=en)
- [Use Google Drive with an iPad or iPhone - Google Drive Help](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2497973?hl=en)
- [Access your files offline - Google Drive Help](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375012?hl=en)